# How to find the exact substring with regex in c++11?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I am trying to find substrings that are not surrounded by other `a-zA-Z0-9` symbols.

For example: I want to find substring `hello`, so it won't match `hello1` or `hellow` but will match `Hello` and `heLLo!@#$%`.
And I have such sample below.

```
    std::string s = "1mySymbol1, /_mySymbol_ mysymbol";
    const std::string sub = "mysymbol";
    std::regex rgx("[^a-zA-Z0-9]*" + sub + "[^a-zA-Z0-9]*", std::regex::icase);
    std::smatch match;

    while (std::regex_search(s, match, rgx)) {
        std::cout << match.size() << "match: " << match[0] << '\n';
        s = match.suffix();
    }
```

The result is:

```
1match: mySymbol
1match: , /_mySymbol_
1match: mysymbol
```

But I don't understand why first occurance `1mySymbol1` also matches my regex?

How to create a proper regex that will ignore such strings?

***UDP***

If I do like this

```
std::string s = "mySymbol, /_mySymbol_ mysymbol";
    const std::string sub = "mysymbol";
    std::regex rgx("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" + sub + "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", std::regex::icase);
```

then I find only substring in the middle

```
1match: , /_mySymbol_
```

And don't find substrings at the beggining and at the end.

Comment: `*` in `[^a-zA-Z0-9]*` means "0 or more", you apparently want "1 or more" that is use `+` character like that `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Comment: @AlexLarionov, I updated the post for your comment

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for Look-behind and Look-ahead https://regex101.com/r/LibWqi/1 ?

Comment: Read more abut regular expressions. There is a word boundary assertion: `\b\w+\b` and it is simplest solution of your problem.

Comment: @MarekR But a word character includes `_`, which won't work for the OP.

Comment: @Kevin This is minor problem: `\b_*mysymbol_*\b` and I'm still not sure how he expect to threat underscores.

Comment: @MarekR That won't match `a_mysymbol_a`. But it's certainly possible that `\b` is perfectly fine for the OP's needs.

Comment: @Kevin first sentence in question says it should not match your example.

Comment: @MarekR No it doesn't? `a_mysymbol_a` is `mysymbol` surrounded by underscores, which is perfectly fine according to the OP. Anything else around it can be ignored. But it doesn't work with your regex `\b_*mysymbol_*\b` because there isn't a word boundary between `a` and `_`. But let's wait for the OP to respond.

Comment: @unDeadHerbs, yeah, that solution work for me,  thank you

Comment: @MarekR, yeah, that solution the simplest and works for me, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `[^a-zA-Z0-9]*` will match 0 or more characters, so it's perfectly valid for `[^a-zA-Z0-9]*mysymbol[^a-zA-Z0-9]*` to match `mysymbol` in `1mySymbol1` (allowing for case insensitivity). As you saw, this is fixed when you use `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` (matching 1 or more characters) instead.

With your update, you see that this doesn't match strings at the beginning or end. That's because `[^a-zA-Z0-9]+` *has* to match 1 or more characters (which don't exist at the beginning or end of the string).

You have a few options:

1. Use beginning/end anchors: `(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|^)mysymbol(?:[^a-zA-Z0-9]+|$)` (non-alphanumeric OR beginning of string, followed by `mysymbol`, followed by non-alphanumeric OR end of string).
2. Use negative lookahead and negative lookbehind: `(?<![a-zA-Z0-9])mysymbol(?![a-zA-Z0-9])` (match `mysymbol` which doesn't have an alphanumeric character before or after it). Note that using this the match won't include the characters before/after `mysymbol`.

I recommend using https://regex101.com/ to play around with regular expressions. It lists all the different constructs you can use.

Comment: Thank you, first solution won't work in case of spaces around substring (https://regex101.com/r/hurSkL/1) , but thank you for your detailed answer, link to a usefull site and second solution!